# Connect to Spark running via YARN through a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark installation running under YARN on a remote cluster, with a firewall between me and the head node. I can use a `ssh` tunnel to access the head node:

```
> ssh -N -f -L 10000:remotenode:10000 between_machine
```

and this setup works, for example, to access a HiveServer2 running on `remotenote`. If Spark was running in cluster mode, I would need to just do the same for the 7077 port and direct the `pyspark` client to `localhost` with

```
> ssh -N -f -L 7077:remotenode:7077 between_machine
> ./pyspark --master spark://localhost:7077
```

How can I do that with Spark running under the YARN scheduler?

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a port to connect, here is a quote from the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html):

> You can access this interface by simply opening
>   http://:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts
>   are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports
>   beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

If you are just looking for a more universal way to get to the host via ssh "tunnel", you could try ssh working as socks proxy:

```
ssh user@host -D 20000
```

And then configuring your browser to connect via socks proxy (host - localhost, port - 20000).

Comment: Thanks. Is the port 4040 the port to connect to the remote pyspark or only for the webui? I need to submit remotely the job, not access the webui.